# Ignore all new incoming mousewheel messages while event is being handled

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, mouse, vcl, mousewheel

I am using some custom combobox control derived from TCustomControl and I am handling mouse events. Let's call it TMyComboBox.

I am handling TMyComboBox.OnChange and doing some operations which takes some time to finish (approx. 200ms) (doing some external hardware changes).

Because I also implemented mouse wheel I am able to change items in my custom combobox with mouse wheel.

Here comes the problem. Mouse wheel event occurs very fast (when scrolling) and this raises OnChange event of my TMyComboBox.

Becuase OnChange takes so much time to finish I can not process all that messages so my combobox is still changing even after I am already not changing mouse wheel anymore. I guess message queue is emptying and sending all mouse wheel events....

So how can I prevent to receive mouse wheel message in message queue if my OnChange is still doing some work?

Pseudo code

```
function TMyComboBox.DoMouseWheelDown(Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Self.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  if (Self.Focused and (Self.IndexSelectData + 1 < FScaleCode.Count ) ) then Self.IndexSelectData := Self.IndexSelectData + 1;
  Self.Cursor := crArrow;
end;

function TMyComboBox.DoMouseWheelUp(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Self.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  if (Self.Focused and (Self.IndexSelectData - 1 > -1 ) ) then Self.IndexSelectData := Self.IndexSelectData - 1;
  Self.Cursor := crArrow;
end;

procedure TMyComboBox.OnChange(Sender: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  -> MessageQueue.Lock; // stop receiving message into queue
  ProcessHardware; // long procedure (approx. 200ms)
  -> MessageQueue.Unlock; // continue recieving message into queue
end;
```

Remark: When setting IndexSelectData, OnChange will be raised.

I read something about PeekMessages but I am not sure how to use it... (if could be used at all)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can stop messages being added to the queue. But you could swallow any messages that are already in the queue:

```
procedure SwallowPendingMessages(hWnd: HWND; MsgFilterMin, MsgFilterMax: UINT);
var
  M: TMsg;
begin
  while PeekMessage(M, hWnd, MsgFilterMin, MsgFilterMax, PM_REMOVE) do begin
    //gulp
  end;
end;
```

You'd call the function at the end of your `OnChange` handler.

I'm not sure that I would go so far as to bless what you are proposing as being a good idea. I think I'd probably be looking for an alternative solution to the problem. Likely one that used threads in order to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Comment: This is it! Until I find better solution like you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: +vote but you can simply disable/enable the combo to prevent receiving further input, then put the focus back in... (Veird comment policy change, can't write +1-...)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm thinking that `ProcessHardware` doesn't pump the queue which means that the messages will queue up. I think disabling would only help if the queue was being serviced in a timely fashion.

Comment: @David - Disabling prevents the system to post input to the box. Seems to work with Sleep.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Does `PostMessage` fail then if the window is disabled? I did not know that.

Comment: @David - No, I don't think it would fail. My point was that the OS wouldn't post input messages to a disabled window. But then maybe it posts to the parent which I didn't test, which could complicate things. Tested now, yours is the better solution, parent receives the wheel message while the combo is disabled.